# brownie cant verify my contract on etherscan

Tags: etherscan, brownie

I am trying to verify a contract (yearn-strategy) that uses the openZeppelin library, other yearn files and a few interfaces for external contracts. The contract deploys just fine but the verification always fails.

I have tried to debug/ investigate further but nothing has worked:

On a related github issue I found "[Make sure all your source files use the same compiler version, otherwise the verification will fail](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/411#issuecomment-761604459)." openzeplin library files all say "pragma solidity ^0.6.0" but my files and the yearn libraries I am using have "pragma solidity 0.6.12", Could this be the issue ?

Etherscan shows a single solidity file "stitched" with all the imported files. How can I make such a file with brownie so I can manually verify on etherscan ?

[contract](https://github.com/praneethmendu/simple-yearn-clone/blob/master/contracts/Strategy.sol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently an issue with brownie verification.

https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1221

It's being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for days and finally here's what worked for me:

I changed my global compiler version to the version of solidity I declared for my contract: 0.6.6 (`from top left...code > preferences > solidity > settings > search solidity > click on solidity configurations > compile using remote version OR just right click on the "pragma solidity..." and select "Change global compiler version"`)

For some reason, this worked. I'm guessing it has something to do with this from the brownie documentation.

**WARNING**: Make sure all your source files use the same compiler version, otherwise the verification will fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. I once had this issue, and the only way I could get around it was copying the source codes of the imported files into specific files and importing these files instead. Them making sure all the files had the same `pragma solidity version` on them.

You might consider try it out.

2. Make sure you set your Infura.io token correctly if you use Infura.